# How can I create a set of dependent select lists where successive lists depend on the choice of preceding list choices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Edit Note at bottom.**

What I am looking to do is create a script that allows me to view a selected option in a `select` element and use that selection as a limiter to what options in a second `select` element can use.

While the example shows a very simple illustration of what I am talking about, I will actually use the code to limit the options of a larger option list. In the larger code, I want to get `option_1_1` to limit options from `selectElement2` to `options_2_1` through `options_2_9`, `option_1_2` limits choices to `option_2_1` through `option_2_11`, and `option_1_3` to limit choices to `option_2_1` through `option_2_5`.

As an example;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- I prefer not to use PHP, but if that's the ONLY way to do it, say so. -->
    <script>
        /* Need script to perform */
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Select element 1 -->
    <select id="selectElement1">
        <!-- If option_1_0 is selected, no options are available in selectElement2 -->
        <option id="option_1_0" value="" selected></option>
        <!-- If option_1_1 is selected, only select options are available in selectElement2 -->
        <option id="option_1_1" value="1" >1</option>
        <!-- If option_1_2 is selected, only select options are available in selectElement2 -->
        <option id="option_1_2" value="2" >2</option>
        <!-- If option_1_3 is selected, only select options are available in selectElement2 -->
        <option id="option_1_3" value="3" >3</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Select element 2 -->
    <select id="selectElement2">
        <!-- Selected by default and cannot change unless a choice is selected from selectElement1 -->
        <option id="option_2_0" value="" selected></option>
        <!-- If option_1_1 is selected, only option_2_1 is available -->
        <option id="option_2_1" value="1">1</option>
        <!-- If option_1_2 is selected, only option_2_1 and option_2_2 are available -->
        <option id="option_2_2" value="2" >2</option>
        <!-- If option_1_3 is selected, only option_2_3 is available -->
        <option id="option_2_3" value="3" >3</option>
        <!-- If option_1_3 is selected, only option_2_3 and option_2_4 are available -->
        <option id="option_2_4" value="4" >4</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
thank you all. you all have helped me a great deal. this is the final working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gradeValue = {};
        gradeValue['A'] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
        gradeValue['B'] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'];
        gradeValue['C'] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

        function changeList() {
            var gradeList = document.getElementById("grade");
            var rankingList = document.getElementById("ranking");
            var selGrade = gradeList.options[gradeList.selectedIndex].value;
            while (rankingList.options.length) {
                rankingList.remove(0);
            }
            var rank = gradeValue[selGrade];
            if (rank) {
                for (var i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) {
                    var ranks = new Option(rank[i], i);
                    rankingList.options.add(ranks);
                }
            }
        } 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="grade" onchange="changeList()"> 
  <option value="">-- Select --</option> 
  <option value="A">A</option> 
  <option value="B">B</option> 
  <option value="C">C</option> 
</select> 

<select id="ranking"></select> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
var selectOne = document.getElementById('selectElement1'),
selectTwo = document.getElementById('selectElement2'),
//set up options (key is equal to the value of the option in selectElement1)
optsList = {
    1: ['option_2_1', 'option_2_2', 'option_2_3', 'option_2_4'],
    2: ['option_2_5', 'option_2_6', 'option_2_7', 'option_2_8'],
    3: ['option_2_9', 'option_2_10', 'option_2_11', 'option_2_12']
};

//add an event listener for the onchange event
selectOne.onchange = function (e) {
    var selectedOpt = this[e.target.selectedIndex],
        optListSet = optsList[selectedOpt.value] || 0;

    //disable all options.
    for(var i=0; i < selectTwo.length; i++){
        selectTwo[i].disabled = "disabled";
    }

    //reset selected option
    selectTwo.children[0].selected = "selected";    

    //loop through the options set corresponding to the value of the selected option
    if(optListSet){
        for (var i = 0; i < optListSet.length; i++) {
            opt = document.getElementById(optListSet[i]);
            opt.disabled = false;
        }
    }

    //enable options list 2
    selectTwo.disabled = false;
};
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgm28b1v/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a change listener on your menu.
Then use the `disabled` attribute to prevent selecting unwanted options:

```
var suffix = jQuery(selectedOption).attr("id").split("_")[2]; // for option_2_3, this hsould be "3"

// loop through all option elements, add a css class to differentiate them from other options.
for(...) {
    // test if the id matches
    var currentIdSuffix = jQuery( currentOption ).attr("id").split("_")[2];
    if( currentIdSuffix != suffix ) {
        // add disabled attribute = prevents selection
        jQuery( currentOption ).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```